# Minimizing sum of distance in a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

> Given that $P$ is a point inside a tetrahedron with vertices at $A, B, C$ and $D$, such that the sum of the distances $PA+PB+PC+PD$ is a minimum, show that the two angles $\angle APB$ and $\angle CPD$ are equal and are bisected by the same straight line. What other pair of angles must be equal?
> My progress: i considered the triangle case scenario and from there i observed angles each make with each other is 120° , now i considered a quadrilateral here i considered making two triangles and observing that the point is lying between the two points which minimize the sum in there . But this tetrahedron i am not getting how to solve like i am considering triangles for lower cases ? Or is there a better method ?

Comment: There are two parts to the proof - first get P that make minimum distance. Then you progress with the second proof - where you show that the bisectors are on same plan.

Comment: For second claim. Let P is sought point and $PA+PB=a$, $PC+PD=b$. Consider two sets of points X, first with $XA+XB=a$ and second $XC+XD=b$. These sets are rotational ellipsoids. If these rotational ellipsoids were intersecting in P, then there were points of one ellipsoid inside of other ellipsoid, but for these points  $XA+XB+XC+XD<PA+PB+PC+PD$ which is contradictory. Then ellipsoids are tangent in P. Then normals of ellipsoids lie at the same straight line. But these normals are angle bisectors of APB and CPD from ellipse properties.

Comment: Very nice method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the tetraedron $ABCD$ is convex it is enough to prove that the requested point $P_0$ is exactly the point where the diagonals $AC, BD$ meet. It is easy to prove that using elementary geometry, as follows: Take any point $P'$ that does not lie on the segment $AC$ then by triangle inequallity we have: $AP'+CP'+DP'+BP'>AC+DB=AP_0+BP_0+CP_0+DP_0$. So  $P_0$ should lie on the segment $AC$. Similar arguments show that any point $P'$ not lying in segment $BD$ gives larger sum of distances from the vertices. So $P_0$ is the desired point. The equality of angles follows immediatelly.

**ADDENDUM**

In case $ABCD$ is a non convex tetrahedron the statement does not apply. For example take the angle $\angle ADC$ bigger than $\pi$ then the only point of the plane that minimizes the sum of distances from each vertex of the $ABCD$ is $D$ itself (there is a similar elementary proof for that). So $P_0=D$. But then $\angle ADB\neq \angle CDD$...

Answer (score 2):

Consider changing sum $S=AP+BP+CP+DP$ with changing vector $\vec{AP}$.
Let mark as vector $\frac{dS}{d\vec{AP}}$ vector with components $(\frac{dS}{dAP_x};\frac{dS}{dAP_y};\frac{dS}{dAP_z})$. For point P making $S$ minimal $\frac{dS}{d\vec{AP}}$ must be zero. $$\frac{d(AP)}{\vec{AP}}=\frac{\sqrt{AP^2}}{\vec{AP}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{AP^2}}\frac{d(AP^2)}{d\vec{AP}}=\frac{1}{2AP}\cdot 2\vec{AP}=\frac{\vec{AP}}{AP}$$
$$\frac{d(BP)}{\vec{AP}}=\frac{\sqrt{BP^2}}{\vec{AP}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{BP^2}}\frac{d(BP^2)}{d\vec{AP}}=\frac{1}{2BP}\cdot \frac{d((\vec{AP}-\vec{AB})^2)}{d\vec{AP}}=\frac{1}{2BP}\cdot 2(\vec{AP}-\vec{AB})=\frac{\vec{BP}}{BP}$$
$$\frac{dS}{d\vec{AP}}=\frac{\vec{AP}}{AP}+\frac{\vec{BP}}{BP}+\frac{\vec{CP}}{CP}+\frac{\vec{DP}}{DP}=0$$

$$\frac{\vec{AP}}{AP}+\frac{\vec{BP}}{BP}=-\left(\frac{\vec{CP}}{CP}+\frac{\vec{DP}}{DP}\right)$$
This claim can be used to solve both parts of problem.

1. Square both sides:

$$2+2\frac{\vec{AP}\cdot \vec{BP}}{AP\cdot BP}=2+2\frac{\vec{CP}\cdot \vec{DP}}{CP\cdot DP}$$
$$2+2\cos APB=2+2\cos CPD\Rightarrow \angle APB=\angle CPD$$

2. Vector $-\left(\frac{\vec{AP}}{AP}+\frac{\vec{BP}}{BP}\right)$ has the same direction as bisector of angle $APB$, and vector $-\left(\frac{\vec{CP}}{CP}+\frac{\vec{DP}}{DP}\right)$ has the same direction as bisector of angle $CPD$, so these two bisectors has opposite directions, therefore they line on the same straight line.